Is there significance to there being “twelve” baskets of leftovers in the Jewish region and “seven” in the gentile?
John 6:1-14 (The western side of the Sea of Galilee is predominantly a Jewish region)

After these things Jesus went over the Sea of Galilee, which is the Sea of Tiberias. 2 Then a great multitude followed Him, because they
saw His signs which He performed on those who were diseased. 3 And
Jesus went up on the mountain, and there He sat with His disciples.
4 Now the Passover, a feast of the Jews, was near. 5 Then Jesus lifted
up His eyes, and seeing a great multitude coming toward Him, He said
to Philip, “Where shall we buy bread, that these may eat?” 6 But this
He said to test him, for He Himself knew what He would do.
7 Philip answered Him, “Two hundred denarii worth of bread is not
sufficient for them, that every one of them may have a little.”
8 One of His disciples, Andrew, Simon Peter’s brother, said to Him, 9
“There is a lad here who has five barley loaves and two small fish,
but what are they among so many?”
10 Then Jesus said, “Make the people sit down.” Now there was much
grass in the place. So the men sat down, in number about five
thousand. 11 And Jesus took the loaves, and when He had given thanks
He distributed them to the disciples, and the disciples to those
sitting down; and likewise of the fish, as much as they wanted. 12 So
when they were filled, He said to His disciples, “Gather up the
fragments that remain, so that nothing is lost.” 13 Therefore they gathered them up, and filled twelve baskets with the fragments of the
five barley loaves which were left over by those who had eaten. 14
Then those men, when they had seen the sign that Jesus did, said,
“This is truly the Prophet who is to come into the world.”

Mark 7:31 (Decapolis is the southeast of the Sea of Galilee which is predominantly Gentile population)

Again, departing from the region of Tyre and Sidon, He came through the midst of the region of Decapolis to the Sea of Galilee.

Mark 8:1-9

In those days, the multitude being very great and having nothing to
eat, Jesus called His disciples to Him and said to them, 2 “I have
compassion on the multitude, because they have now continued with Me
three days and have nothing to eat. 3 And if I send them away hungry
to their own houses, they will faint on the way; for some of them have
come from afar.”
4 Then His disciples answered Him, “How can one satisfy these people
with bread here in the wilderness?”
5 He asked them, “How many loaves do you have?”
And they said, “Seven.”
6 So He commanded the multitude to sit down on the ground. And He took
the seven loaves and gave thanks, broke them and gave them to His
disciples to set before them; and they set them before the multitude.
7 They also had a few small fish; and having blessed them, He said to
set them also before them. 8 So they ate and were filled, and they
took up seven large baskets of leftover fragments. 9 Now those who had
eaten were about four thousand. And He sent them away,

Is there significance to there being “Twelve” baskets of bread leftover in the Jewish region and “seven” in the gentile?

 Note: see my previous question -
Where did Jesus perform the “Feeding of the 4,000"? 

Studies have shown that gentiles actually eat 12/7 or 171%  as much as Jews? The 12 baskets left over symbolized the 12 tribes of Israel, while the 7 gentile baskets represented the 7 gentile ethnicities in attendance? Or maybe 12+7 = 19, which is a very mysterious number According to one website, "In ancient Egyptian numerology, the number 19 was revered for its association with the Sun and the concept of rebirth. Additionally, it was believed to represent the cycle of life, death, and regeneration, reflecting the cyclical nature of existence." :o  Or maybe it's simply a lot left over. ;-)

I think the feeding of the 5,000 - the distribution and the gathering in - is specific to the mission "to the lost sheep of Israel".
As per Isa 11.10, 12:

10 In that day the root of Jesse, who shall stand as a signal for the
peoples 12 He will raise a signal for the nations and will assemble
the banished of Israel, and gather the dispersed of Judah from the
four corners of the earth.

This is the Didache, giving insight into the meaning of the eucharist.

And concerning the broken bread: We thank You, our Father, for the
life and knowledge which You made known to us through Jesus Your
Servant; to You be the glory forever. Even as this broken bread was
scattered over the hills, and was gathered together and became one, so
let Your Church be gathered together from the ends of the earth into
Your kingdom; (ch 9)
Remember, Lord, Your Church, to deliver it from
all evil and to make it perfect in Your love, and gather it from the
four winds (ch 10)

In short, I imagine the 5 loaves are 5 books of the Torah. Fishes the Major and Minor prophets, maybe.
Jesus gives the loaves to the disciples, and they to the crowd. This represents the teaching, which goes to the ends of the earth. But the second part is the return, of the banished/dispersed.
Originally that was the 12 tribes. (Later it comes to be the Church).
TBH, my provisional opinion is that the 4,000 was a bowdlerized Roman version of the story, and the numbers have no particular significance. (Luke is right to omit it.)
I know that this goes against Mark 8.17-21, where it is strongly implied that there is a mystery in the numbers of the two miracles together. After decades of pondering, my provisional view is that this is just Mark teasing us with Mystery. If the book belonged to a group, there must have been an answer, but I'm assuming it would be bogus. (I could very well be wrong!!)


Bible scholars believe that the amount of the leftover food is
symbolic in both cases. Seven baskets were left over when Jesus fed
the 4,000, and the number seven symbolizes spiritual completion and
perfection in the Bible.
In the case of the feeding of the 5,000, 12 baskets were left over
when Jesus fed 5,000 people, and 12 represents both the 12 tribes of
Israel from the Old Testament and Jesus' 12 apostles from the New
Testament. [1]

One possible connection:
The Significance of ‘Twelve’:
“Twelve” in the Bible refers to completeness and is often associated with the people of God. For the feeding miracle which took place in a predominantly Jewish region, the twelve baskets of leftovers could represent the twelve tribes of Israel. Perhaps this is to show Jesus’ provision for the whole of Israel.

Genesis 49:28 - All these are the twelve tribes of Israel, and
this is what their father spoke to them. And he blessed them; he
blessed each one according to his own blessing.

The Significance of ‘Seven’:

Deuteronomy 7:1 - “When the Lord your God brings you into the land
which you go to possess, and has cast out many nations before you, the
Hittites and the Girgashites and the Amorites and the Canaanites and
the Perizzites and the Hivites and the Jebusites, seven nations
greater and mightier than you,

On the other hand, the number “seven” in the Bible is frequently associated with perfection and completeness. In the feeding miracle which occurred in the predominantly Gentile region of Decapolis, the seven baskets of leftovers might represent the seven Gentile nations that God told Moses He would cast out of the promised land.
This could symbolize Jesus’ provision extending to the Gentiles as well.
Conclusion:
These miracles, therefore, could be interpreted as symbolic demonstrations of Jesus’ ability to provide abundantly for both Jews and Gentiles. It conveys a profound message that Christ’s provision is not only perfect but also complete, extending its reach to both Jews and Gentiles. A demonstration of the universal provision of Christ.




References:




1
Hopler, W. (2018, June 22). The miracle of Jesus feeding 4,000 people. Learn Religions. https://www.learnreligions.com/miracles-of-jesus-feeding-the-hungry-124510#:~:text=Bible%20scholars%20believe%20that%20the%20amount%20of%20the,symbolizes%20spiritual%20completion%20and%20perfection%20in%20the%20Bible.


2
Graham, J. (2011, February 8). Why were there 12 baskets of leftovers? Christianity.com. https://www.christianity.com/jesus/life-of-jesus/miracles/why-were-there-12-baskets-of-leftovers.html


3
TWELVE BASKETS - Why twelve? Because it symbolizes something. (n.d.). https://www.bibleversestudy.com/johngospel/john6-twelve-baskets.htm


4
Wikipedia contributors. (2024b, July 25). Biblical numerology. Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_numerology




This is best explained by placing it in a table:



Incident
Feeding 5000
Feeding 4000




Starting material (supplied by humans)
5 loaves
7 loaves


Number miraculously fed
5000
4000


Leftovers
12 baskets
7 baskets



In summary:

the less God has to start with, the greater the miracle!
the more we depend on God, the greater His work

